# Render tokens in hook_node_view

Tags: 7, hooks, tokens, nodes

I am creating the following pseudo field in hook_node_view:

```
function user_guides_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    $node->content['field_mytest'] = array('#markup' => '<p>This is my test</p><p>[current-page:title]</p>');
}
```

This is the rendered result:

```
This is my test
[current-page:title]
```

How can I get the value of the token to be displayed instead of the token itself?

Comment: `#markup` is raw HTML markup (eg, the final product). you must 1st pass your `token` value through a render function.

Comment: Is there something already that I can pass a block of text through with the token somewhere in the middle, and it parses the token out of the text and replaces it with its value?

Comment: Question: Why do you need to use tokens in first place? You have the node object, and all the static variables that you can access with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`token_replace()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7) for that. As you're using a global token (no context required) it's very simple:

```
$markup = token_replace('<p>This is my test</p><p>[current-page:title]</p>');
$node->content['field_mytest']['#markup'] = $markup;
```